# Simplificar código empleando *args o **kwargs (u otra forma si fuera mejor)

Tags: python

Estoy intentando mejorar mis código intentando evitar duplicar código. En este caso hay un momento en mi proyecto que tengo que calcular en función de un valor X (eje x) el valor Y (eje y) de una gráfica con forma trapezoidal.

Para esto he creado tres funciones, una para cuando la gráfica tiene la forma trapezoidal completa, y otras dos cuando falta uno de los costados. A continuación muestro un ejemplo visual y mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def trapezoide(val,x):
    a,b,c,d = val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]

    if x < a or x > d:
        re = 0
    elif a <= x <= b:
        re = (x-a)/(b-a)
    elif b <= x <= c:
        re = 1
    elif c <= x <= d:
        re = (d-x)/(d-c)
    return re

def trapezoidal_in_L(val,x):
    a,b = val[0], val[1]
    if x < a:
        re = 0
    elif a <= x <= b:
        re = (x-a)/(b-a)
    elif x > b:
        re = 1
    return re

def trapezoidal_in_R(val,x):
    c,d = val[1], val[2]
    if x > d:
        re = 0
    elif c <= x <= d:
        re = (d-x)/(d-c)
    elif x < c:
        re = 1
    return re
```

Donde `val` son los puntos en el eje X que forman la gráfica y `x` es el input de estudio.

La cosa es, la primera función ya contiene las otras dos. Por lo tanto, estoy seguro que de alguna manera se puede solo emplear la primera función.

Ahora mismo esto no es posible pues, cuando `val` va variando en función de la forma de la gráfica y por lo tanto en la forma completa son 4 valores pero las otras dos son solo 3, representando estos diferentes posiciones.

Yo se que siempre podría pasar 4 valores, de manera que las posiciones no se alterasen y que esos que no interesen fueran por ejemplo un `false` y trabajar con booleanos en mi función trapezoidal principal para entender que tipo de gráfico es. Pero considero que sigue no siendo la mejor manera. Mi pregunta es, he estado leyendo sobre el tema de `*args` y `**kwargs` pero no consigo usarlos bien. ¿Se puede hacer así o no es lo más óptimo? ¿alguien sabe con solo la función principal como se podría hacer?

Como digo, mi código ya es funcional, pero quiero dar un paso más a la hora como codificar.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

¿Cómo se identifica cuando es, por ejemplo, la forma R? `val = [False, False, 3, 7]`

Si es así, el código se puede reducir preguntando en los `if` si determinado valor es cualquier cosa menos `False` y luego comparando con los demás datos:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> a = False
>>> a and x < a
False
>>> a = 4
>>> a and x < a
True
```

Guiándonos de esto, se puede reducir el código así:

```
def trapezoide(val, x):
    a,b,c,d = val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]
    if (a and x < a) or (d and x > d):
        re = 0
    elif (a and x >= a) and (x <= b):
        re = (x-a)/(b-a)
    elif (b and x >= b) and (x <= c):
        re = 1
    elif (c and x >= c) and (x <= d):
        re = (d-x)/(d-c)
    else:
        re = 1
    return re
```

Haciendo algunas pruebas:

```
val = [3, 4, 6, 9]
for n in range(11):
    print(trapezoide(val, n))
# 0 0 0 0.0 1.0 1 1 0.6667 0.3333 0.0 0
```

Para `val = [False, False, 6, 9]`, `# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0.6667 0.3333 0.0 0`

Para `val = [3, 7, False, False]`, `# 0 0 0 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0 1 1 1`

### *args

En el caso de `*args`, se le pueden pasar indefinidos parámetros a la función y esta los recibirá en una tupla. El nombre `*args` es solo una convención, tu le puedes poner lo que quieras, como `*mi_var`

```
def f(*args):
    print(*args)

f(4, 8, 3)
# (4, 8, 3)
```

Usar `*args` no te va a servir mucho para este problema, porque la función no sabrá qué posición le corresponde a cada item de los parámetros. A menos que se lo mandes como tupla o diccionario, pero ya para eso mejor usa `**kwargs`

### **kwargs

Igual que el caso anterior, el nombre *kwargs* es solo una convención, puedes ponerle como desees, la magia lo hacen los `**`. 
`**kwargs` recibe indefinidos parámetros en forma de diccionario, lo cual si podría ser útil para resolver el problema.

```
def trapezoide(x, **val):
    # se hace un checkeo de qué valores se mandaron
    a = val['a'] if 'a' in val else False
    b = val['b'] if 'b' in val else False
    c = val['c'] if 'c' in val else False
    d = val['d'] if 'd' in val else False
    # Lo demás queda intacto respecto al primer caso
    if (a and x < a) or (d and x > d):
        re = 0
    elif (a and x >= a) and (x <= b):
        re = (x-a)/(b-a)
    elif (b and x >= b) and (x <= c):
        re = 1
    elif (c and x >= c) and (x <= d):
        re = (d-x)/(d-c)
    else:
        re = 1
    return re
```

Ahora llamando a la función

```
for n in range(11):
    print(trapezoide(n, c=6, d=9))
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0.6667 0.3333 0.0 0
```